# How to reason about levels of an enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an account model with an enum defined as

```
enum access: [:basic, :silver, :gold, :platinum]
```

I would like to reason about the level of the account e.g

```
account.gold!
account.access < 'silver'
```

but `account.access < 'silver'` returns `true`, presumably because the `< override` for `string` is being used.  How do do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the underlying value of access in the database is integer, then this can be done using the rails `_before_type_cast` method e.g.

```
  def access_lt(level)
    access_before_type_cast < Account.accesses[level]
  end
```

so then

```
account.gold!
account.access_lt 'silver' # false
```

Comment: I will consider an answer that does this more elegantly by safely overriding ```<``, i.e ```account.golf < 'silver' # false